# How to suppress Xcode emitting -stdlib flag?

Tags: c++, xcode, linker, g++

I am attempting to build using GCC 4.8 from within Xcode, following [this](http://hamelot.co.uk/programming/add-custom-compiler-to-xcode/) procedure (only using version 4.8 instead of 4.7).

After fixing a few minor build failures, my project compiles correctly, but linking fails with the following error:

> g++-4.8: error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libc++'

The `-stdlib=` flag is supported by LLVM, but not GCC, hence the error.

In **Build Settings**, there is a `CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY` flag under the **User-Defined** heading. When I change the value of this flag, the error changes to reflect the current value. However, I cannot remove this flag from the project entirely.

Is there a way to stop Xcode from emitting the `-stdlib=` flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XCode 6 you can select `C++ Standard Library` to `Compiler Default`. XCode then won't produce the `-stdlib=` option.